# Imageview in Titanium Appcelerator not display

Tags: android, imageview, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am having a hard time to display the image in an ImageView in titanium, I run the app in an emulator

Here is my .xml file code

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <View id="view_image">
        <ImageView id="img_logo" />
    </View>
</Window>
```

And here is my .tss code

```
"#img_logo":{
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
image: '/images/storm_logo.png'
```

}

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix would be to specify the image inside the imageView tag.

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <View id="view_image">
        <ImageView id="img_logo" image='/images/storm_logo.png' />
    </View>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where have you put your image?

The way you refer to the image via the id in the tss file seems Ok. It does the same as explained by Funtik

However, your image have to be in the directory: `app/assets/images` (as you are using Alloy). Is that the position of the image? Also, if the image is in that directory, check if it is 'Ok'. Does it show correctly if you double-click on it?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it's legal to refer to the image inside *.tss file

Comment: Thanks John, the image already appear when I created a folder name images inside the assets folder.

Comment: Question, does the image inside the assets/android/images/res-long-land-hdpi, ldpi, mdpi cannot be fetch when I run the app in an emulator the image does not appear inside the folder of the different dpi? what seems to be the problem of that?

Comment: @Funtik, yep - I would think so. It works, anyway - not sure about the "legal" issue though ;-)

Comment: @SydneyLoteria, I haven't got a lot of experience with Android - yet. However, on iOS it works like this: If there is an image in the specific platform folder (under assets/iphone/images) then that one is used. Else a general one from assets/images will be used. As far as I know that is the same for Android. What I don't know is the exact rules that are used to pick from which subfolder (depending on the device characteristics). I know there are some fallback rules - try to search within ticonf and tidev.